# Weird memory problem

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nszombie, nsmutabledata

At some point I allocate a NSMutableData element like this:

```
NSMutableData* data=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
```

Later, I do:

```
NSString *dataAsStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
completeCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
    incompleteMessage,
    [dataAsStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, i-startIndex)]];         
[incompleteMessage release];
incompleteMessage = nil;
[dataAsStr release];
```

And finally I call:

```
[data release]; //Here I get a BAD_ACCESS error since data gets a release count of -1
```

Now according to instruments (Allocations with zombie support), the first line of the second block NSString *dataAsString = ... calls [data release]

Where does that happen?

Comment: could you post the complete method, seems this problem is not within the scope of posted code.

Comment: Try just [[NSMutableData alloc] init]. Maybe it helps.

Comment: What are you doing with data before playing with dataAsStr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistery is solved..
Its a rather big method, so I didn't realize that [data release]; was in a loop and its alloc was not. That was causing the zombie.